# Search Open Multilingual Wordnet with JWI

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet, jwi, open-multilingual-wordnet

Does JWI support the Open Multilingual Wordnet or (even better) the Extended Open Multilingual Wordnet? Both of those data sets look great, but they extremely clunky as is. It looks like I would have to parse and aggregate a dozen (or hundred in the case of EOMW) indices and merge the same number of dump files. Has anyone done this using JWI? Is there an alternative implementation that more easily supports either multilingual wordnets? They show a demo in SQL -- is a dump available anywhere?